# How to change a value based on a condition in other column in R?

Tags: r

I want to change the values in a column based on another column.

If terminate_dyad 0 or NA then type.of.termination must be 0. If terminate_dyad 1 then type.of.termination must keep the value it has.

I tried to do that with `case_when` like that:

```
df %>%
  mutate(type.of.termination = case_when(terminate_dyad == 0 ~ 0))
```

However, I couldn't figure out to change NA to 0, and keep to values if terminate_dyad == 1.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(type.of.termination = replace(type.of.termination, terminate_dyad %in% c(0, NA), 0))

# or

df %>%
  mutate(type.of.termination = ifelse(terminate_dyad %in% c(0, NA), 0, type.of.termination))
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit to try to return what OP is asking for:

```
df %>%
  mutate(type.of.termination = case_when(is.na(terminate_dyad) ~ 0,
                                         terminate_dyad == 0 ~ 0,
                                         TRUE ~ type.of.termination))
```

```
# A tibble: 15 × 3
   dyadid terminate_dyad type.of.termination
    <dbl>          <dbl>               <dbl>
 1      1              0                 0  
 2      3              0                 0  
 3      3              0                 0  
 4      3              0                 0  
 5      3              0                 0  
 6      3              0                 0  
 7      4              0                 0  
 8      4              0                 0  
 9      4              0                 0  
10      7              1                NA  
11      7              0                 0  
12      7              0                 0  
13      7              1                NA  
14     11              1                 1  
15     12              1                 6.1
```

Comment: in that method, type.of.termination does not keep the value; it changes all values to 1 if the terminate_dyad is 1. For instance, dyadid 12 must stay as 6.1.

Comment: I have just changed last part and it works: df %>%
  mutate(type.of.termination = ifelse((is.na(terminate_dyad) | terminate_dyad == 0), 0, type.of.termination))